# why is json_decode of my php program does not returns object type

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to json_decode on the API server of mine from my react app with fetch and decode a JSON data change into an object, but even after adding the false option, it still keeps returning array-type.

json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),false) //not working

I can get the data with array-type: $data['hoge'] but not $data->hoge

```
async submit(ev) {
        // User clicked submit
        ev.preventDefault();

        const data = {name: this.state.name, email: this.state.email};


        let {token}= await this.props.stripe.createToken(data);
        const post_data = JSON.stringify({token_id: token.id, site_id: this.state.site_id});


        let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8888/API/API/contact/create.php", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.key}`
            },
            body: post_data
        });

        if (response.ok) console.log("Purchase Complete!")


    }
```

```php
// Get raw data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),false);

//var_dump
ob_start();
var_dump($data);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
error_log($content,3,'./debug.txt');

error_log('site_id', $data->site_id);
```

var_dump result: 
/Users/k/Desktop/APPS/sql-test/API/API/contact/create.php:40:
        null

```
    /Users/k/Desktop/APPS/sql-test/API/API/contact/create.php:40:
    object(stdClass)[9]
    public 'token_id' => string 'tok_22vj0dL6qGzdvjd1tM2mAcfl' (length=28)
    public 'site_id' => string '15' (length=2)
```

Error log of the error_log('site_id', $data->site_id):

[14-Jul-2019 00:28:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'site_id' of non-object in /Users/k/Desktop/APPS/sql-test/API/API/contact/create.php on line 49
[14-Jul-2019 00:28:50 UTC] site_id

Comment: result of `var_dump($data);` please? I suspect `$data` being an array of objects

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Cid. I've added the result of var_dump.

Comment: try like this please once error_log('site_id '. $data->site_id);

Comment: What are you `var_dump()`ing exactly? You've shown two outputs: `null` and the object you're looking for.

Comment: result of the error_log for the 'site_id' shows only "site_id" but not the data I decoded and get the notice "trying to get...".

Comment: Hmmm. why am I seeing the "NULL" at the first line of var_dump(). I've only var_dump()ed once as I renewed my post. Through the $data straight into the var_dump($data) right after the json_decode().

Comment: When `json_decode()` returns `null` it typically means that input is not valid JSON. In such case you can see the exact error message with [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/json_last_error_msg) and you also log the raw input. That situation is not difficult to happen—for instance, if you merely point your browser to `create.php`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try to simply cast $data as object?

```
$dataObject = (object) $data;
```

And than try:

```
error_log('site_id', $data->site_id);
```

BR

Comment: What is this good for? If `json_decode(..., false)` doesn't return an object it means it's either returning `null` because it failed or the encoded data isn't an object at all (e.g. `"[3, 14, 16]"`).